# Why am I unable to build a statically linked, single-threaded Boost library?

Tags: c++, boost

I've checked out the Boost library (v1.68.0) from https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git and performed the usual `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`. I'm interested in building a statically linked, single-threaded version of the library. So I run:

```
./bootstrap.sh && ./b2 link=static threading=single
```

But this fails (see output below). What am I doing wrong?

```
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset darwin... tools/build/src/engine/bin.macosxx86_64/b2
Detecting Python version... 2.7
Detecting Python root... /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
Unicode/ICU support for Boost.Regex?... not found.
Backing up existing Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam.1
Generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam...

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:

    ./b2

To adjust configuration, edit 'project-config.jam'.
Further information:

   - Command line help:
     ./b2 --help

   - Getting started guide:
     http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

   - Boost.Build documentation:
     http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/index.html

Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : 64-bit
    - default architecture     : x86

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


    - symlinks supported       : yes
    - C++11 mutex              : no
    - lockfree boost::atomic_flag : yes
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_auto_declarations : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_constexpr : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_defaulted_functions : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_final : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_hdr_mutex : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_hdr_tuple : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_lambdas : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_noexcept : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_nullptr : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_rvalue_references : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_template_aliases : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_thread_local : no
    - Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_variadic_templates : no
    - has_icu builds           : no
warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components.
note: to enable them, add "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam
    - zlib                     : yes
    - bzip2                    : yes
    - lzma                     : yes
warning: Skipping Boost.Locale library with threading=single.
    - native-atomic-int32-supported : yes
    - native-syslog-supported  : yes
    - pthread-supports-robust-mutexes : no
    - compiler-supports-visibility : yes
    - compiler-supports-ssse3  : yes
    - compiler-supports-avx2   : no
    - gcc visibility           : yes
    - long double support      : yes
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
    - libbacktrace builds      : no
    - addr2line builds         : yes
    - WinDbg builds            : no
    - WinDbgCached builds      : no
    - BOOST_COMP_GNUC >= 4.3.0 : no
warning: Skipping Boost.Thread library with threading=single.
warning: Skipping Boost.Wave library with threading=single.
error: Name clash for '<pstage/lib>libboost_system.a'
error:
error: Tried to build the target twice, with property sets having
error: these incompatible properties:
error:
error:     -  <threading>single
error:     -  <threading>multi
error:
error: Please make sure to have consistent requirements for these
error: properties everywhere in your project, especially for install
error: targets.
```

Comment: C++ is supposed to be multithreaded.

Comment: @VTT Rather, allows for multithreading since C++11. Nobody is *forced* to use the feature. And if the target is really single-threaded, adding synchronisation "just in case" is a waste. Even if probably not significant.

Comment: @Deduplicator Unless program runs on bare metal (which is clearly not happening in this case) multithreading support is mandatory *4.7 Multi-threaded executions and data races [intro.multithread] Under a hosted implementation, a C ++ program can have more than one thread running concurrently.  Under a freestanding implementation, it is implementation-defined whether a program can have more than one thread of execution.*

Comment: @VTT Nobody can force you to use all the features. And if you don't use a feature, how would you detect whether code took advantage of that under the as-if-rule? The exact performance isn't covered. Of course, promising part of the tool-chain that there won't be no multi-threading, and still using it anyway, would be contra-indicated.